# publish link in facebook application android

Tags: android, facebook

I want to publish string in facebook how to do it

```
mPostButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mFacebook.dialog(Main_fb.this, "feed",new SampleDialogListener());

                //I want to add EditText="link";

            }
        });
```

how can I  do it??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly than you can't put any text in EditText of Facebook Post Page. But you can attach link to the post and preview it.
Like this:

```
mPostButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("link", "http://itunes.apple.com/"); // Your link
        mFacebook.dialog(Main_fb.this, "feed", params, new SampleDialogListener());
    }
});
```